# Ativar espaçamento de variáveis Code::Blocks

Tags: c, c++, ide, codeblocks

Eu amo o Code::Blocks, só que tem um problema, eu queria que ele já espaçasse as instruções assim que eu colocar o ';' igual o Visual Studio. Ex:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)`` >> ``for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Instale o [*plugin* AStyle](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Source_Code_Formatter_plugin). Acredito que ele resolva o que deseja.